# Bold black cursor in Eclipse deletes code, and I don't know how to get rid of it

Tags: java, eclipse, text-cursor

When I edit code in the middle of statements, it replaces the current code around it. I cannot find a way to replace this with a normal cursor that only inserts data instead of replacing it. Is that functionality possible in Eclipse?

[image: Look at the black cursor to the right of the 3rd statement]

Answer (score 61):

The problem is also identified in your status bar at the bottom:

[image: overwrite label in status bar]

You are in overwrite mode instead of insert mode.

**The “Insert” key toggles between insert and overwrite modes.**

Comment: For me pressing Insert key was not doing anything, so I restarted my Eclipse and it automatically solved this problem!

Answer (score 26):

It sounds like you hit the "Insert" key .. in most applications this results in a fat (solid rectangle) cursor being displayed, as your screenshot suggests. This indicates that you are in *overwrite* mode rather than the default *insert* mode.

Just hit the "insert" key on your keyboard once more... it's usually near the 'delete' (not backspace), scroll lock and 'Print Screen' (often above the cursor keys in a full size keyboard.)
This will switch back to insert mode and turn your cursor into a vertical line rather than a rectangle.

Answer (score 12):

You might have pressed `0` (also used for insert, shortcut `INS`) key, which is on the right side of your right scroll button. To solve the problem, just press it again or double click on 'overwrite'.

Answer (score 5):

This problem, in my case, wasn't related to the Insert key. It was related to Vrapper being enabled and editing like Vim, without my knowledge.

I just toggled the Vrapper Icon in Eclipse top bar of menus and then pressed the Insert Key and the problem was solved.

Hopefully this answer will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it's related to the **Toggle Vrapper Icon** in the Eclipse.

If you are getting the bold black cursor, then the icon must be enabled. So, click on the Toggle Vrapper Icon to disable. It's located in the Eclipse's Toolbar. Please see the attached image for the clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue can happen not only in [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) but also in any of the [text-editor](/questions/tagged/text-editor).

On [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) systems, [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) in my case, this issue arose when the <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>insert</kbd> key was pressed in tandem unintentionally which takes the user to the **overwrite** mode.

To get back to **insert** mode you need to press <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>insert</kbd> in tandem again.